# Правильно ли согласовано причастие?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, причастия

Какое правильное окончание в слове "примененной"? И почему?

*Скульптура есть результат физической процедуры по исключению лишнего, **примененной** к глыбе камня.*

Или же:
*Скульптура есть результат физической процедуры по исключению лишнего, **примененный** к глыбе камня.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понимаю так: для того, чтобы получить результат (то есть скульптуру), к глыбе камня надо применить ***процедуру*** по исключению лишнего — согласуем со словом "процедуры".

Можно другими словами: Скульптура есть результат физической, примененной к глыбе камня процедуры по исключению лишнего.

*Скульптура есть* (что?) *результат* (чего?) *физической **процедуры** по исключению лишнего,* (какой) ***примененной*** к глыбе камня.